# TypeError: response.sendStatus is not a function

Tags: express, sequelize.js

this is my error . whats wrong?

```
TypeError: response.sendStatus is not a function
```

I want check in users table if i have not a record create this and if i have a record update it

Now this work but server sends status `500`
and i have this error `response.sendStatus is not a function`

```js
exports.updateuser = (request, response, next) => {
  UsersModel.findOne({ where: { Authid: authid } }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    if (response === null) 
    next(
       UsersModel.create({
          Authid: authid,
          nationalCode,
          shopName,
          post,
          phoneNumber,
          address,
          email,
          logestic,
          postcode,
          imgVcf,
          imgVcb,
          imgSh1,
          imgSh2,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          response.sendStatus(200);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          res.send(err);
        })
    )  
    else next(
       UsersModel.update(
        {
          nationalCode,
          shopName,
          post,
          phoneNumber,
          address,
          email,
          logestic,
          postcode,
          imgVcf,
          imgVcb,
          imgSh1,
          imgSh2,
        },
        { where: { Authid: authid } }
      )
        .then((response) => {
          response.sendStatus(200);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          res.send(err);
        })
    )
  });
};
```

Comment: try giving findOne parameter a different name than response, because now response is the result of the findOne function not express response

Answer (score 0):

`updateuser` controller takes request and response object.
The response object is being overriden by the callback in then block in here

```
UsersModel.findOne({ where: { Authid: authid } }).then((response) => {
  // response variable now holds data received from findOne method.
...
}
```

Resolve the naming collision and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use Node.JS without Express. If so, use the '=' operator:

```
response.sendStatus = 200;
```

> Enjoy!